# How to manage network traffic from local machine with qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, proxy, traffic

How to manage network traffic from local machine with qt c++? I found solutions for packet capturing e.g libpcap, but they can not block or manipulate traffic. I need to create something similar to Proxy Switcher and cant find right spot to start from. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Qt does not provide a way to sniff or block network traffic. On windows you can use [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) which is a port of libpcap and offers lots of low-level network features, including the ones you need, that you can use from user-mode. WinPcap consists of a driver and a library that is used to easily access the low-level network layers. Some networking tools like Wireshark, Nmap, Snort, ntop use WinPcap. On Linux you can use libPcap to sniff network packets but for blocking i think you need a kernel space driver or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Qt does not provide filtering facilities. To filter traffic on Linux, you should use iptables.

```
apt-get install iptables-dev
```

http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/group__Queue.html

> When the decision on a packet has been choosed, the verdict has to be given by calling nfq_set_verdict() or nfq_set_verdict2(). The verdict determines the destiny of the packet as follows:
>
> - NF_DROP discarded the packet
> - NF_ACCEPT the packet passes, continue iterations
> - NF_STOLEN gone away
> - NF_QUEUE inject the packet into a different queue (the target queue number is in the high 16 bits of the verdict)
> - NF_REPEAT iterate the same cycle once more
> - NF_STOP accept, but don't continue iterations